# Add an identifier column for each row from each file. and to apply index for each file name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported multiple CSV files into SQL database in SSMS. That means, one table "Disputes" is created by adding records from 3 different CSV files. I need to add an identifier column to understand that which row belongs to which file. I'm thinking to add an index for each file name.

If anyone can, please give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do that *before* you import the data, not after. You'll need to `TRUNCATE` your table and load the files again, making sure you add the new column in your ETL process.

Comment: As mentioned by Larnu you should add this in the ETL. We usually add the columns `SourceFileName` and `ImportTimestamp` to each CSV Importer ETL - this provides the possibility to identify the Source of your data as well as the timestamps when records have been imported. The last mentioned comes in handy when there is a possibilty that files are imported more than once.

Comment: Thank You for your response.  I added a new column for storing source file names as [FIle Name], but how can I add the source file names into this column.